# Using ReactJs to fetch data from an api but getting a blank page with no error

Tags: reactjs, api

Hello Guys kindly someone assist me with the issue i am having with my code. I am a newbie trying to learn react. i am trying to fetch data from an api. From the browser console i can see the data but when i try to return the data in the Dom i get a blank page. see my code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class FetchApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      person: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/")
      .then(res => res.json())

      .then(data => console.log(data))

      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          person: data
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.person &&
          this.state.person.map(item => (
            <li key={item.results.id}>
              {item.results.gender} {item.results.location}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FetchApi;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code to the following. In some cases the way you are referencing the properties was wrong. Have made some changes in your componentDidMount and in the render method.

Sandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-nubu7

Hope this resolves

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      person: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            person: data.results
          });
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.person &&
          this.state.person.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id.value}>
              {item.gender} {item.location.city}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-api-1lcse), the response from the fetch API is in this format

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "gender":"male",
         "name":{
            "title":"Monsieur",
            "first":"Alois",
            "last":"Fernandez"
         },
         "location":{
            "street":{
               "number":1856,
               "name":"Rue Duquesne"
            },
            "city":"Untereggen",
            "state":"Genève",
            "country":"Switzerland",
            "postcode":9650,
            "coordinates":{
               "latitude":"-50.1413",
               "longitude":"-23.6337"
            },
            "timezone":{
               "offset":"+5:30",
               "description":"Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi"
            }
         },
         "email":"alois.fernandez@example.com",
         "login":{
            "uuid":"04b2ee45-cf07-4015-a5d8-2311f6dc28a1",
            "username":"ticklishleopard228",
            "password":"forward",
            "salt":"V8bDcgux",
            "md5":"d521c6488fc4644ccb7e670e9e67bc20",
            "sha1":"9673afe219f27817c573a9cb727c209357d386ef",
            "sha256":"c13a5bc77dc720a6cc46bc640680e9501225fc94c9bc6ba7fe203fe989a992a0"
         },
         "dob":{
            "date":"1957-11-24T13:46:29.422Z",
            "age":63
         },
         "registered":{
            "date":"2003-05-18T19:56:11.397Z",
            "age":17
         },
         "phone":"077 871 56 07",
         "cell":"077 461 83 98",
         "id":{
            "name":"AVS",
            "value":"756.1050.9271.56"
         },
         "picture":{
            "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/8.jpg",
            "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/8.jpg",
            "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/8.jpg"
         },
         "nat":"CH"
      }
   ],
   "info":{
      "seed":"76a6b875b2ba81dd",
      "results":1,
      "page":1,
      "version":"1.3"
   }
}
```

So you have to set the `person` in the state to `data.results` instead of `data` and access the `item` in the results accordingly.